# findAssocs and numeric(0)

Tags: r, text, text-mining, tm

I am attempting to find words associated with a particular word in a term document matrix using the tm package.

I always getting `numeric(0)` as my result
example;

```
findAssocs(myTdm, "evrensel", 0.25)
numeric(0)
```

`numeric(0)`, what's that mean? i wanna find the relationship. Any advice is highly appreciated!

Comment: what happens when you use values less than 0.25?

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont have any terms which correlate to evrensel with correlation factor more than 0.25